# Consulta SQL a dos tablas

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Buenas a todos!!!

Quiero hacer una consulta SQL que me recupere todos los campos de la tabla PRODUCTO cuyo campo id se encuentre en la tabla VENTAS, la tabla VENTAS tiene como campos : idProducto, idVenta, Observación y la tabla PRODUCTO tiene idProducto, precio, descripción.

La consulta que he pensado es:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM `producto` 
   WHERE `idProducto`= 
       (SELECT idProducto 
           FROM `ventas` 
           WHERE `idProducto`=6)
```

Al probarlo en phpMyAdmin me da el error de que la subconsulta tiene varios registros, ¿cómo se puede hacer una consulta de este tipo? Es usando `JOIN`? 
Muchas gracias

Comment: simplemente reemplaza tu `=` por un `IN`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!!  @Lamak justo lo acabo de ver aqui [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597620/1242-subquery-returns-more-than-1-row-mysql]

Comment: Parece que ya está solucionado pero en la consulta inicial en el WHERE no se pone "=" sino IN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrias realizar una consulta como esta:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM producto 
    JOIN ventas ON ventas.idProducto = producto.idProducto 
    WHERE producto.idProducto = 6
```

Primero, realizamos el `JOIN` uniendo la tabla `ventas` con la tabla `producto`.

```
JOIN ventas
```

Segundo, indicamos la union que se realizara entre las tablas:

```
ON ventas.idProducto = producto.idProducto
```

Tercero indicamos la condicion:

```
WHERE producto.idProducto = 6
```

Comment: La consulta con `JOIN` no es necesariamente equivalente a lo que quiere el op. Por ejemplo, en caso que la tabla `VENTAS` tenga un `idProducto` repetido (que puede suceder perfectamente), tu consulta duplicará los resultados. Además, al usar `SELECT *`, estás seleccionando todas las columnas de ambas tablas

Comment: Usar `SELECT * ...` es una mala práctica en SQL, porque casi siempre te llama columnas de la tabla que no vas a usar. Se nota poco en tablas pequeñas, pero en tablas grandes afecta la rapidez y el rendimiento de las consultas.

Comment: @Lamak Si, tienes razon, solo que al ver que el vuelve a hacer una condicion en la que selecciona de otra tabla un elemento con un identificador (_suponiendo que el identificador es unico_), supuse que seria mejor si usara el `JOIN`

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo se, puse el `SELECT *` debido a que queria tratar de guardar el formato original de la pregunta, aunque sea una mala practica.

Comment: @IvanBotero Lo imaginaba, el comentario iba dirigido al autor de la pregunta :). Saludos.

Comment: Deberías aclarar que no es necesario hacer consultas anidadas en este caso

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.* FROM PRODUCTO P,
VENTAS V
WHERE P.IDPRODUCTO=V.IDPRODUCTO
```

No entiendo porque pones idproducto=6, no especificas que quieras precisamente ese producto, pero si es así, entonces la consulta sería de esta manera:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.* FROM PRODUCTO P,
VENTAS V
WHERE P.IDPRODUCTO=V.IDPRODUCTO
      AND V.ID_PRODUCTO=6
```

Comment: @Ivan Botero, he puesto 6 por poner algo, en mi script de php obtengo esa variable mediante el metodo $_POST[], me interesaba saber si era IN o JOIN, acabo de empezar con SQL y todo lo que no sea coger datos de una sola table de momento me viene grande, aunque gracias a vuestras colaboraciones se entiende todo mucho mejor

Comment: Entiendo, bueno pues que bueno que te sirvan los comentarios, puedes utilizar un JOIN o dejarlo como lo puse en el comentario. Estamos para ayudarnos.

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola! Al principio tenía el mismo problema que tú. Pero es sencillo:

> Seleccionar todas las columnas:

```
SELECT *
```

> Tabla 1:

```
FROM Producto
```

> Tabla 2 en unión con la tabla 1:

```
JOIN Ventas
```

> Hacer la union de la tabla 1 y la tabla 2:

```
ON Ventas.CodigoProducto = Producto.CodigoProducto
```

> Cuando el código del producto sea igual a 6:

```
WHERE Producto.CodigoProducto = 6
```

¡Éxito! :)